# PayPal support for "free" item -- possible use of Sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox

I am using `Joomla/php` to invoke PayPal production.  All works fine until the business owner requests a particular coupon should trigger a free item (which is an advertisement, so shipping does not apply.) Paypal does not support a `zero-cost (free)` item upon check-out.  I have full access to the php code that invokes PayPal.  What if I direct the coupon to a `sandbox`?  Your thoughts, please.

Comment: As far as I know, zero cost items are fine when checked out with payed for items. If this is a zero priced basket, can you not just bypass the paypal process all together? Using sandbox as a hack to get it to work is imo a bad idea. That means keeping track of 2 systems, one of which isn't to be considered a reliable source and makes product tracking difficult.

Comment: Jon -- good response.  Yes, it is a zero priced basket.  Agreed that bypassing PayPal would do it.  However, the Joomla component I am using marks the item production, paid, and gives it an expiration date upon a successful PayPal.